# select statement in a Case statement

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I want to write a select statement on the condition in CASE . For e.g If (today is weekday) then x else y

I wrote the following statement in a stream analytics query

```
      SELECT
                CASE
                    WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EventTime) in (1,7) THEN  SELECT count(*) as Eventcount
                                                               INTO output
                                                               FROM Input
                                                               Group By  tumblingwindow(minute,5)
                                                               Having Count(*) < 10
                    ELSE                                       SELECT count(*) as Eventcount
                                                               INTO output
                                                               FROM Input
                                                               Group By  tumblingwindow(minute,5)
                                                               Having Count(*) > 10
                     END as DayStatus
            INTO Output1
            FROM Input
```

I tried below query too but still not working
SELECT(
CASE
WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EventTime) in (1,7) THEN
(
SELECT count(*) as Eventcount
INTO EmailADOutputEventsEprism
FROM IE_Eprism
Group By  tumblingwindow(minute,5)
Having Count(*) > 10
)
ELSE 'Weekday'
END ) as DayStatus

```
            FROM IE_Date
```

I am getting the error on above statement.
How can I achieve this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If its just two conditions, then you could have 2 independent queries in the same ASA job. Would that work?

Comment: Thanks @SidRamadoss, I am trying the same approach now. but the disadvantage of this approach is we have to create 2 different output (using more resources). And even with this approachin my case it is still not giving me desired output. It is not giving any error but not working well. For weekdays i tried
    SELECT count(*) as Eventcount
     INTO Output
     FROM Input
    where DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EventTime)  in (1,7)
    Group By tumblingwindow(minute,5)
gives me 0 which is not true

Comment: You could use the same output resource in both queries. I recommend you try using Visual Studio Code to test your query locally on your device using input streaming from cloud -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/visual-studio-code-local-run-live-input this will allow you to debug query more effectively. You'll know exactly what results your query produce.

Comment: Thanks @SidRamadoss, I will try to debug

Answer (score 1):

In SQL one can not choose the whole row-set based on a condition in SELECT clause.
Combining similar computations can be done either by factoring out common expression parts or by authoring separate queries and combining the results using UNION or JOIN into a single output.

Looking at the specific query in the question first approach of factoring common expressions is a much simpler path to take:

```
WITH agg AS (
    SELECT [day] = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EventTime),
           count = Count(*)
    FROM Input
    GROUP BY  TumblingWindow(minute,5)
)

SELECT count
FROM agg
WHERE CASE WHEN [day] in (1,7) and count < 10 THEN 1
           WHEN [day] in (2,3,4,5,6) and count > 10 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
      END = 1
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to copy the GROUP BY from the original query. Updated...